# Choosing a relay for 1kW switching

Tags: power, relay, switching

I am making a project for some practical application. I require to use a relay which can control up to 1kW AC power. Though there are cheap 5V relays available with about 220VAC and 10A rating which satisfy the requirement but I highly doubt their truthfulness and lifetime. At the same time I want to make the project cheap so I want to avoid costlier ones. Can someone please suggest a good compromise between the choices. And how far can I probably go with the ratings of cheap ones(rough idea).

Comment: If something seems to be too good or too cheap to be true, it probably is. Are you offering a lifetime guarrantee with a free warranty, or does the poor sucker who bought it bear the repair cost? It all depends on your integrity, would you build your life-support system with these? If you don't want to guess, then buy some, and set up an accelerated life testing rig.

Comment: The very cheap Asian sourced relays with basic drive electronics are potential disaster sources. The "best" protection is to design absolutely within specification and THEN use a brand whose reputation AND provenance is well known.  Jeroen3 mentions Omron - their products are essentially always top quality and specifications meaningful. An informal but reasonably good method is to see if [DIGIKEY}(https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=relay%20ac) sell the brand. They seldom sell junk. Note my comment on "provenance". Good enough products tend to be counterfeited. ...

Comment: ...  A reliable supplier is a reasonable but not perfect guarantee against that.  Where are you located? I'd be happy to comment further off-list if you wish - as the question has been put on hold here. See my profile for email address.

Comment: Cheap cheap ... : At a minimum - load them to their max spec and switch them repeatedly with a load with worst case characteristics that they should handle. Watch them die :-(. (Ask me how I know :-) - you have to try these things ! :-) ). || Note that many cheap relays have a VERY NASTY and dangerous relay form factor where the midle contact of the SPDT output lies between or near the coil pins so that "creepage distance" is reduced from "would have been 1"+ if sensibly built"  to "dangerously small" . Do not use them on anything where having mains AC on the coild is unnacceptable :-(   :-) .

Answer (score 2):

> Though there are cheap 5V relays available with about 220VAC and 10A rating which satisfy the requirement but I highly doubt their truthfulness and lifetime

A good relay is not cheap. It's cost anywhere between $2-4 and has a usable life of around 50k operations or less. (more for signal relays)
To prevent arcing when opening a strong spring is used, requiring a higher current to compress when closing. Coil power will go up with contact rating.
For example, an Omron [G5Q](https://omronfs.omron.com/en_US/ecb/products/pdf/en-g5q.pdf) relay available in a high capacity version SPST-NO is capable of switching max 10A with 250Vac **resistive** load.

For actual 10A rated *breaking* current you'd want to search above 250 Vac maximum contact rating. My example is 277 Vac.

This relay specifies 25,000 operations at 10 A with 250 VAC resistive load.

A solid state relay from Crydon for example will have infinite operations, but is $25 and requires a heatsink.
Running your own SSR with a triac can be cheaper than that, if the application allows it.

Mechanical relays are not that expensive after all...